# 4 fixed width columns with top-left box spanning 2 columns. Centered. How?

Tags: css

Each column has a fixed width of 200px with a 20px margin.
The top-left box and the columns have variable height.

Like this

[image]

Tor Valamo kindly provided an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894884/4-columns-elastic-css-with-top-left-box-spanning-2-columns-how) (that being elastic, this is fixed), but I cant centre the layout, as it uses `position: absolute`.

How can I do it? I know that using a table with colspan and rowspan the answer to this problem is trivial, but I would like to avoid table-based layout like the plague!

Comment: Why, using tables for layout, of course! *(Ducks and runs)* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but something like this...?

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <div style="width: 420px;">top</div>
    <div style="width: 200px; float: left;">bottom left</div>
    <div style="width: 200px; float: left;">bottom right(ish)</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">big left box</div>
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">big right box</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the layout that you linked to and have it be centered, despite the `position: absolute`. I've adapted it for you here (you'll have to tweak to add in the margins, but it works, I tested it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #outer, #left, #right, #top_left, #bottom_left,
        #bottom_left_left, #bottom_left_right, #right_left, #right_right {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }
        #outer {margin:0 auto; position:relative;width:800px;}
        #left {right:50%;width:400px;}
        #top_left {position:relative; width:400px;}
        #bottom_left {position:relative;}
        #bottom_left_left {right:50%; width:200px;}
        #bottom_left_right {left:50%; width:200px;}
        #right {left:50%;}
        #right_left {right:50%; width:200px;}
        #right_right {left:50%; width:200px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="left">
            <div id="top_left">Top left</div>
            <div id="bottom_left">
                <div id="bottom_left_left">Bottom left</div>
                <div id="bottom_left_right">Bottom right</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="right_left">Near Right</div>
            <div id="right_right">Far Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```